# winston postgresql custom sql/ tableName not working

Tags: node.js, postgresql, winston

```
const logger = new (winston.Logger)({
  transports : [
    new winston.transports.PostgreSQL({
      connString :   'xxxxxxxxxxx',
      schema : 'public',
      //tableName : 'logEntry',
      customSql:'INSERT INTO public."logEntry"(logLevel, msg, meta) VALUES ($1, $2, $3);',
    })
  ];
});
```

Data is not inserted into the table and I get a warning in the console:

> Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code?

Comment: Try defining an error handler like `logger.transports.PostgreSQL.on('error', err => console.log('Error while inserting data'));` and see if it is working.

Comment: It helped for  me. Thank you.

Comment: Great!.. I'll post this as an answer.. Can you please upvote/accept it answered please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created table using sequelize with timestamp enabled, Here inserting data manually means it won't add createdAt column, that causes issue.
replacing 
customSql:'INSERT INTO public."logEntry"(logLevel, msg, meta) VALUES ($1, $2, $3);',
with 
customSql: 'INSERT INTO public."logEntry"("logLevel", msg, meta,"createdAt") VALUES ($1, $2, $3,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);',
solved the issue.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an error handler like to overcome this error message,

```
logger.transports.PostgreSQL.on('error', err => 
    console.log('Error while inserting data')
);
```

Hope this helps!.

Comment: I get a warning in the console:

Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Warning can be ignored as long as it is not blocking the code execution.

Comment: Can we add postgres transport to winston-express-middleware